# How to use cross-encoder with Huggingface transformers pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers, large-language-model

There're a set of models on huggingface hubs that comes from the `sentence_transformers` library, e.g. https://huggingface.co/cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1

The suggested usage examples are:

```
# Using sentence_transformers

from sentence_transformers import CrossEncoder

model_name = 'cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1'
model = CrossEncoder(model_name)
scores = model.predict([
  ['How many people live in Berlin?', 'How many people live in Berlin?'], 
  ['Berlin has a population of 3,520,031 registered inhabitants in an area of 891.82 square kilometers.', 'New York City is famous for the Metropolitan Museum of Art.']
])
scores
```

[out]:

```
array([ 0.36782095, -4.2674575 ], dtype=float32)
```

Or

```
# From transformers.

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
import torch

# cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-12-v2
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')

features = tokenizer(['How many people live in Berlin?', 'How many people live in Berlin?'], 
                     ['Berlin has a population of 3,520,031 registered inhabitants in an area of 891.82 square kilometers.', 'New York City is famous for the Metropolitan Museum of Art.'],  
                     padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    scores = model(**features).logits
    print(scores)
```

[out]:

```
tensor([[10.7615],
        [-8.1277]])
```

If a user wants to use the `transformers.pipeline` on these cross-encoder model, it throws an error:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
import torch

# cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-12-v2
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')

pipe = pipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

It throws an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_108/785368641.py in <module>
----> 1 pipe = pipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py in pipeline(task, model, config, tokenizer, feature_extractor, image_processor, framework, revision, use_fast, use_auth_token, device, device_map, torch_dtype, trust_remote_code, model_kwargs, pipeline_class, **kwargs)
    711         if not isinstance(model, str):
    712             raise RuntimeError(
--> 713                 "Inferring the task automatically requires to check the hub with a model_id defined as a `str`."
    714                 f"{model} is not a valid model_id."
    715             )

RuntimeError: Inferring the task automatically requires to check the hub with a model_id defined as a `str`.
```

**Q: How to use cross-encoder with Huggingface transformers pipeline?**

**Q: If a model_id is needed, is it possible to add the model_id as an `args` or `kwargs` in `pipeline`?**

There's a similar question [Error: Inferring the task automatically requires to check the hub with a model_id defined as a `str`. AraBERT model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74425802/error-inferring-the-task-automatically-requires-to-check-the-hub-with-a-model-i) but I'm not sure it's the same issue, since the other question is on `'aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv02'` but not the cross-encoder class of models from `sentence_transformers`.

Comment: Seems like I've to write my own pipeline =( https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/add_new_pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error and code digging from

- This part of the code will contains the list of available pre-coded pipeline tasks `https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py`
- This is where it document how you can input the text pairs to the model `https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py#L121`
- This is where the general usage of how the `text-classification` task was coded and the usages are in the docstrings of the functions https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py

And now, here goes...

## TL;DR

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
import torch

# cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-12-v2
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')

pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)


pipe([{"text": 'How many people live in Berlin?', "text_pair": 'Berlin has a population of 3,520,031 registered inhabitants in an area of 891.82 square kilometers.'},
      {"text": 'How many people live in Berlin?', "text_pair": 'New York City is famous for the Metropolitan Museum of Art.'},
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.99997878074646},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.0002951461647171527},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.027012893930077553}]
```

## But the output isn't the same as using `sentence_transformers`!

Yes it isn't, because softmax was applied to the outputs.

There's a classification function that is applied post model inference, at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py#L27

```
class ClassificationFunction(ExplicitEnum):
    SIGMOID = "sigmoid"
    SOFTMAX = "softmax"
    NONE = "none"
```

And particularly at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py#L184

```
    def postprocess(self, model_outputs, function_to_apply=None, top_k=1, _legacy=True):
        # `_legacy` is used to determine if we're running the naked pipeline and in backward
        # compatibility mode, or if running the pipeline with `pipeline(..., top_k=1)` we're running
        # the more natural result containing the list.
        # Default value before `set_parameters`
        if function_to_apply is None:
            if self.model.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification" or self.model.config.num_labels == 1:
                function_to_apply = ClassificationFunction.SIGMOID
            elif self.model.config.problem_type == "single_label_classification" or self.model.config.num_labels > 1:
                function_to_apply = ClassificationFunction.SOFTMAX
            elif hasattr(self.model.config, "function_to_apply") and function_to_apply is None:
                function_to_apply = self.model.config.function_to_apply
            else:
                function_to_apply = ClassificationFunction.NONE
```

## TL;DR (this time for real)

To replicate the results from rolling out your own tokenize + forward function, you'll have to explicitly set the classification function and override the post-process function, i.e.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers.pipelines.text_classification import ClassificationFunction


model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('cross-encoder/mmarco-mMiniLMv2-L12-H384-v1')

pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, function_to_apply=ClassificationFunction.NONE)


pipe([{"text": 'How many people live in Berlin?', "text_pair": 'Berlin has a population of 3,520,031 registered inhabitants in an area of 891.82 square kilometers.'},
      {"text": 'How many people live in Berlin?', "text_pair": 'New York City is famous for the Metropolitan Museum of Art.'},
      {"text": 'Hello how are you?', "text_pair": "I'm fine, thank you"},
      
     ])
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 10.761542320251465},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': -8.127744674682617},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': -3.5840566158294678}]
```

Comment: Now the other question is why the `sentence_transformers` outputs are different from `automodel` from huggingface? *Shrugs...